# Distinct Sum and Group by

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, impala

I have a dataset [attached example] and I want to create 2 tables out of this;

```
+------+------------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| corp |  product   | data  | Group | sales | market |
+------+------------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| A    | Eli        | 43831 | A     |   100 | I      |
| A    | Eli        | 43831 | B     |   100 | I      |
| B    | Sut        | 43831 | A     |    80 | I      |
| A    | Api        | 43831 | C     |    50 | C or D |
| A    | Api        | 43831 | D     |    50 | C or D |
| B    | Konkurent2 | 43831 | C     |    40 | C or D |
+------+------------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
```

1st - sum(sales) by market and exclude duplicated rows, so  I want to end up with Sales for each market in specific date rage (Data column) but exclude duplicated - I have them because 1 product can be in more than 1 group

So  first table, for exmaple, for MRCC I, would look like:

```
+--------+-------+-------+
| market | sales | data  |
+--------+-------+-------+
|  I     |   180 | 43831 |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

Then second table I would like to look like above one, but add as a 'dictionary' aditionall column with uniqe product name within Market and Date, so for MRCC I it would look like:

```
+--------+-------+-------+----------------+
| market | sales | data  | unique product |
+--------+-------+-------+----------------+
| I      |   180 | 43831 | eli            |
| I      |   180 | 43831 | Sut            |
+--------+-------+-------+----------------+
```

The thing is, im not that experienced in SQL, and i'm fairly new to DataProcessing, the system I am working in allows me to do some of data processing either by some "visual" recipes or by SQL code which im not that familiar with. And even moe confusing is I can choose between 3 SQL DBMS , Impala, Hive, Spark SQL - for example to create market column I used Impala and script looks like this, and im not sure if this is "pure" Impala syntax:

```
SELECT * from
(  
   -- mrc I --
    SELECT *,case when 
    (`product`="Eli") 
    or
    (`product`="Sut")  
    THEN  "MRCC I"
    end as market
    FROM x.`y`  
  )a
where market is not null
```

Could you give me some tips on a structure of a code and if this is even possible?

Thanks,
eM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  import spark.implicits._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  case class Sale(
                 corp:    String,
                 product: String,
                 data:    Long,
                 group:   String,
                 sales:   Long,
                 market:  String
                 )

  val df = Seq(
    Sale("A", "Eli", 43831, "A", 100, "I"),
    Sale("A", "Eli", 43831, "B", 100, "I"),
    Sale("A", "Sut", 43831, "A", 80, "I"),
    Sale("A", "Api", 43831, "C", 50, "C or D"),
    Sale("A", "Api", 43831, "D", 50, "C or D"),
    Sale("B", "Konkurent2", 43831, "C", 40, "C or D")
  ).toDF()

  val t2 = df.dropDuplicates(Seq("corp", "product", "data", "market"))
    .groupBy("market", "product", "data").sum("sales")
    .select(
      'market,
      col("sum(sales)").alias("sales"),
      'data,
      'product.alias("unique product")
    )

  t2.show(false)
//  +------+-----+-----+--------------+
//  |market|sales|data |unique product|
//  +------+-----+-----+--------------+
//  |I     |80   |43831|Sut           |
//  |I     |100  |43831|Eli           |
//  |C or D|40   |43831|Konkurent2    |
//  |C or D|50   |43831|Api           |
//  +------+-----+-----+--------------+

  val t1 = t2.drop("unique product")
    .groupBy("market", "data").sum("sales")
    .select(
      'market,
      col("sum(sales)").alias("sales"),
      'data)

  t1.show(false)
//  +------+-----+-----+
//  |market|sales|data |
//  +------+-----+-----+
//  |I     |180  |43831|
//  |C or D|90   |43831|
//  +------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure If I will use this script in my case, but for sure it helped me understand the logic behind what I have to do, step by step!